# React Router not rendering components at all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

Components render fine if I add them directly but the router will not render anything. I just get a blank page at every route, no errors in console or anything.

**My App.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './pages/editor'
import './css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';
import Editor from './pages/editor';
import Preview from './pages/preview';
import Home from './pages/home';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <Router>
        <div className="app-wrapper" id="App">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact componenet={Home} />
            <Route path="/editor" exact componenet={Editor} />
            <Route path="/preview" exact componenet={Preview} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>

    )
  }

}

export default App;
```

Components are all very basic except for the Editor.

**preview.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Preview extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>Welcome to the preview page</div>
        )

    }
}

export default Preview;
```

home.js is basically the same. No idea why this isn't working and this is the first time I've used BrowserRouter. Still learning react so thanks for the help.

Comment: Make sure that div isn’t causing issues in App. Try removing it? Actually that shouldn’t be the issue.

Comment: If you add `<Route component={() => <p>Catch all test</p>} />` after the preview route, do you see anything ?

Comment: I think it’s a spelling mistake. Change “componenet” to “component” in each <Route>.

Comment: @evolutionxbox omg. Thanks! That was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your component spellings are incorrect

```
<Route path="/" exact componenet={Home} />
```

Should be

```
<Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
```

Comment: yeah, that was it. Someone responded with that in the comments. 

<aside>Whos leg do I gotta hump for some upvotes so I can get enough rep to upvote people's answers? lol</aside>